# DatePicker and TimePicker API < 11

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I was looking for in the forum and in the web, but I can't find a solution for my problem.
I am working in a program that uses a DatePicker and a Timepicker. In my program I used the Google default definition for Pickers (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) with a separeted class for each picker(time and date).

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
```

This is the DatePickerFragment class:

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            (OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
}
    }
```

I read something about support libraries and to change my activity to FragmentActivity, but I got some errors.
How should I change my code to implement that in versions lower than 3.0?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: make your imports from android.support.v4

Comment: I made that and I changed the extends Activity for FragmentActivity and getFragmentManager() for getSupportFragmentManager(), but there is the error, in the last change :S

Comment: Finally, it worked!! Thank you for your advice pedromss

Comment: Post an answer saying how you solved it and accept it - that' the way in SO

Comment: Thank you again for your advise, it is nice for me to learn these things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
The problem here was that I was using **android.app.DialogFragment** instead of **android.support.v4 .app.Dialog.Fragment**.
So, I imported android.support.v4 library to my three classes (MainActivity, DatePickerFragment  and TimePickerFragment.

Next step was changing the *extends* of my MainActivity class from **Activity** to **FragmentActivity** (changing the imports statements):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {}
```

Finally, I changed **getFragmentManager()** for **getSupportFragmentManager()** in both classes:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); 
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Last step was testing on the android 2.3.3 emulator and it worked correctly.